# Reading and writing from child processes while alive and running

Tags: c, process, pipe

I'm looking to pipe information between a parent and a child. Currently, I'm piping from the parent's STDERR to the child's STDIN and Reading the Child's STDOUT through reading the other end of the file descriptor. I've done the following below but am struggling with the child needing to exit before I am able to read. How can I constantly read line by line the child's output

Loops between child processes

```
for (int currentP = 0; currentP < inputs.playerCount; currentP++) {
            char currentPlayerC[2];
            sprintf(currentPlayerC, "%d", currentP);
            char* currentPlayerT = argv[3+currentP];

            int fds[2];
            int fds1[2];
            pipe(fds);
            pipe(fds1);
            char buff[10];
            memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
            if ((pids[currentP] = fork()) < 0) {
                    perror("fork");
                    abort();
            } else if (pids[currentP] == 0) { //Child
                    close(fds[PIPE_READ]);
                    close(fds1[PIPE_WRITE]);
                    dup2(fds[PIPE_WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO);
                    dup2(fds1[PIPE_READ], STDIN_FILENO);
                    close(fds1[PIPE_READ]);
                    close(fds[PIPE_WRITE]);
                    execlp(CHILD PROCESS THAT PRINTS TO STDOUT READS FROM STDIN))
                    _exit(0);
                    return BADSTART;
            } else  { //parent
                    dup2(fds1[PIPE_WRITE], STDERR_FILENO);
                    close(fds[PIPE_WRITE]);
                    close(fds1[PIPE_READ]);
                    fprintf(stderr, "game_over\n"); //ENDS CHILD
                    read(fds[PIPE_READ], buff, sizeof(buff));
                    //Will continue forever unless I put in game_over
                    close(fds1[PIPE_WRITE]);
                    close(fds[PIPE_READ]);
            }
```

}

Comment: You receive output from the child as soon as the child writes the output. Perhaps you need to adjust the buffering strategy in the child, e.g. by turning off buffering for `stdout` or by calling `fflush()` at appropriate points.

Comment: The OPs question is about a run time problem, but the posted code is just a fragment.  Please post a [mcve]

Comment: regarding: `_exit(0);
        return BADSTART;`  The 'return' statement will NEVER be executed

Comment: regarding: `execlp(CHILD PROCESS THAT PRINTS TO STDOUT READS FROM STDIN))
        _exit(0);`  a 'exit' value of 0 indicates success, but `execlp()` only returns if there was a error.  Suggest: `execlp(CHILD PROCESS THAT PRINTS TO STDOUT READS FROM STDIN));  perror( "execlp failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line:

```
read(fds[PIPE_READ], buff, sizeof(buff));
```

will wait FOREVER if the child exited.

Suggest:

```
if( wanting child to exit )
{
    int status;
    fprintf(stderr, "game_over\n"); //ENDS CHILD
    wait( &status );
    return 0;
}

fprintf( stderr, "next command to child\n" );
read(fds[PIPE_READ], buff, sizeof(buff));
```